# How to select a contact with ABPeoplePickerNavigationController in Swift?

Tags: swift, addressbook, abaddressbook, peoplepicker, addressbookui

I have added the `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` into my first view controller. I want that when I select a contact show the info to show in other view controller, but I'm trying use my code and this not show never when I click in a contact. This only open the contact into native app `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController`.

```
var people = ABPeoplePickerNavigationController()
var addressBook: ABAddressBookRef?

func extractABAddressBookRef(abRef: Unmanaged<ABAddressBookRef>!) -> ABAddressBookRef? {
    if let ab = abRef {
        self.view.addSubview(people.view)
        return Unmanaged<NSObject>.fromOpaque(ab.toOpaque()).takeUnretainedValue()
    }
    return nil
}
```

I tried this function

```
func peoplePickerNavigationController(peoplePicker: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController!,didSelectPerson person: ABRecordRef!) {

    var unmanagedEmails = ABRecordCopyValue(people, kABPersonEmailProperty)
    let emailObj: ABMultiValueRef = Unmanaged.fromOpaque(unmanagedEmails.toOpaque()).takeUnretainedValue() as NSObject as ABMultiValueRef

    var index = 0 as CFIndex

    var unmanagedEmail = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emailObj, index)
    var emailAddress:String = Unmanaged.fromOpaque(unmanagedEmail.toOpaque()).takeUnretainedValue() as NSObject as String

    println(emailAddress)      
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

1. Have you set the `peoplePickerDelegate` property of the `people` picker controller? If you don't do that, it won't know to try to call these methods in your class. Thus:

   ```
   people.peoplePickerDelegate = self
   presentViewController(people, animated: true, completion: nil)
   ```
2. Your example method is referencing `people` when you call `ABRecordCopyValue`. That's your picker controller. I assume you meant to reference `person`, the `ABRecordRef!` that was passed as a parameter.

   You might also want to make sure you actually have an email address before trying to access it. You can use `ABMultiValueGetCount`.

   I also think you can also eliminate that `fromOpaque`/`toOpaque` dance.

   This yields:

   ```
   func peoplePickerNavigationController(peoplePicker: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController, didSelectPerson person: ABRecord) {
       let emails: ABMultiValueRef = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty).takeRetainedValue()
       if ABMultiValueGetCount(emails) > 0 {
           let index = 0 as CFIndex
           let emailAddress = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emails, index).takeRetainedValue() as! String

           print(emailAddress)
       } else {
           print("No email address")
       }
   }
   ```
3. If you need to support iOS 7, too, use:

   ```
   func peoplePickerNavigationController(peoplePicker: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController, shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson person: ABRecord, property: ABPropertyID, identifier: ABMultiValueIdentifier) -> Bool {
       let multiValue: ABMultiValueRef = ABRecordCopyValue(person, property).takeRetainedValue()
       let index = ABMultiValueGetIndexForIdentifier(multiValue, identifier)
       let email = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multiValue, index).takeRetainedValue() as! String

       print("email = \(email)")

       peoplePicker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

       return false
   }
   ```
4. You might, though, rather than assuming the user only wanted the first email address, instead, let them click through and pick one of the possible multiple email addresses the contact had. So, first, you might want to eliminate some of the "noise", by telling the picker that you only want to see email addresses:

   ```
   people.peoplePickerDelegate = self
   people.displayedProperties = [NSNumber(int: kABPersonEmailProperty)]
   presentViewController(people, animated: true, completion: nil)
   ```

   And then, remove the prior method we've been discussing, and instead implement:

   ```
   func peoplePickerNavigationController(peoplePicker: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController!, didSelectPerson person: ABRecordRef!, property: ABPropertyID, identifier: ABMultiValueIdentifier) {
       let multiValue: ABMultiValueRef = ABRecordCopyValue(person, property).takeRetainedValue()
       let index = ABMultiValueGetIndexForIdentifier(multiValue, identifier)
       let email = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multiValue, index).takeRetainedValue() as String

       println("email = \(email)")
   }
   ```

   And to support iOS 7,0, too, you'd add:

   ```
   func peoplePickerNavigationController(peoplePicker: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController, shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson person: ABRecord, property: ABPropertyID, identifier: ABMultiValueIdentifier) -> Bool {
       let multiValue: ABMultiValueRef = ABRecordCopyValue(person, property).takeRetainedValue()
       let index = ABMultiValueGetIndexForIdentifier(multiValue, identifier)
       let email = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multiValue, index).takeRetainedValue() as! String

       print("email = \(email)")

       peoplePicker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

       return false
   }
   ```
5. By the way, iOS 8 offers a feature to control whether a contact is enabled or not. Since you're supporting iOS 7 and 8, you'd want to employ that conditionally, such as:

   ```
   if people.respondsToSelector(Selector("predicateForEnablingPerson")) {
       people.predicateForEnablingPerson = NSPredicate(format: "emailAddresses.@count > 0")
   }
   ```

   This gives the user visual indication whether there is even an email address for the individual, and prevents them from selecting entry without email address.

Obviously, if using iOS 9 and later, you should retire all of this and use the `ContactsUI` framework, which simplifies the code further.

Comment: I have added thisfunctions, and write the code delegage, but this not open the function when I click into a contact.. I have class ViewPeopleController: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController, ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate{ declaration and people.peoplePickerDelegate = self  in viewDidLoad.  What can I be doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Could you upload your code-project to any place? Now I going to update my code question. Thanks!

Comment: I've uploaded my demo to https://github.com/robertmryan/PeoplePickerSwiftDemo, but there's really nothing more than what you see above in my answer.

Comment: I have detect my problem, the function to select a contact: func peoplePickerNavigationController(peoplePicker: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController!, didSelectPerson person: ABRecordRef!) {   only is called in ios 8.0 simulator. I was trying this in ios 7.1 simulator. What need I make to call this function in -8.0? Thanks!!

Comment: If you look at the documentation for `ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate`, you'll see the deprecated methods you should use if your target was pre iOS 8 (e.g. `shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson`).

Comment: Now the problem is that dismissViewControllerAnimated not function, if I select a contact in ios7 this is open, and not copy and dimiss viewController like in ios8 code. And in cancel button I have the same problem

Comment: I solve this with: if (ABMultiValueGetCount(emails) > 0) {
            let index = 0 as CFIndex
            let emailAddress = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emails, index).takeUnretainedValue() as String
            
            peoplePicker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
            return emailAddress
        } else {
            return "No email address"
        } in shouldContinue and adding this to didCancel: peoplePicker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)  Really thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 18):

Here is the latest framework for iOS 9 - ContactsUI

1. import ContactsUI
2. Conform to the [CNContactPickerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/ContactsUI/Reference/CNContactPickerDelegate_Protocol/index.html) (No required methods)
3. Create a contacts picker object and present it:

   ```
   let peoplePicker = CNContactPickerViewController()

   peoplePicker.delegate = self

   self.presentViewController(peoplePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
   ```
4. Dismiss the CNContactPickerViewController in the contactPickerDidCancel delegate function

   ```
   func contactPickerDidCancel(picker: CNContactPickerViewController) {
       picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
   }
   ```
5. Here is how I Accessed a contacts name, phone numbers, phone number labels, and photo using the didSelectContact delegate function:

   ```
   func contactPicker(picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelectContact contact: CNContact) {
   //Dismiss the picker VC
   picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
   //See if the contact has multiple phone numbers
   if contact.phoneNumbers.count > 1 {
       //If so we need the user to select which phone number we want them to use
       let multiplePhoneNumbersAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Which one?", message: "This contact has multiple phone numbers, which one did you want use?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
       //Loop through all the phone numbers that we got back
       for number in contact.phoneNumbers {
           //Each object in the phone numbers array has a value property that is a CNPhoneNumber object, Make sure we can get that
           if let actualNumber = number.value as? CNPhoneNumber {
               //Get the label for the phone number
               var phoneNumberLabel = number.label
               //Strip off all the extra crap that comes through in that label
               phoneNumberLabel = phoneNumberLabel.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("_", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
               phoneNumberLabel = phoneNumberLabel.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("$", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
               phoneNumberLabel = phoneNumberLabel.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("!", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
               phoneNumberLabel = phoneNumberLabel.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("<", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
               phoneNumberLabel = phoneNumberLabel.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(">", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
               //Create a title for the action for the UIAlertVC that we display to the user to pick phone numbers
               let actionTitle = phoneNumberLabel + " - " + actualNumber.stringValue
               //Create the alert action
               let numberAction = UIAlertAction(title: actionTitle, style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (theAction) -> Void in
                   //Create an empty string for the contacts name
                   var nameToSave = ""
                   //See if we can get A frist name
                   if contact.givenName == "" {
                       //If Not check for a last name
                       if contact.familyName == "" {
                           //If no last name set name to Unknown Name
                           nameToSave = "Unknown Name"
                       }else{
                           nameToSave = contact.familyName
                       }
                   }else{
                       nameToSave = contact.givenName
                   }

                   // See if we can get image data
                   if let imageData = contact.imageData {
                       //If so create the image
                       let userImage = UIImage(data: imageData)
                   }
                   //Do what you need to do with your new contact information here!
                   //Get the string value of the phone number like this:
                   actualNumber.stringValue  
               })
               //Add the action to the AlertController
               multiplePhoneNumbersAlert.addAction(numberAction)
           }
       }
       //Add a cancel action
       let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: { (theAction) -> Void in
           //Cancel action completion
       })
       //Add the cancel action
       multiplePhoneNumbersAlert.addAction(cancelAction)
       //Present the ALert controller
       self.presentViewController(multiplePhoneNumbersAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }else{
       //Make sure we have at least one phone number
       if contact.phoneNumbers.count > 0 {
           //If so get the CNPhoneNumber object from the first item in the array of phone numbers
           if let actualNumber = contact.phoneNumbers.first?.value as? CNPhoneNumber {
               //Get the label of the phone number
               var phoneNumberLabel = contact.phoneNumbers.first!.label
               //Strip out the stuff you don't need
               phoneNumberLabel = phoneNumberLabel.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("_", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
               phoneNumberLabel = phoneNumberLabel.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("$", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
               phoneNumberLabel = phoneNumberLabel.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("!", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
               phoneNumberLabel = phoneNumberLabel.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("<", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
               phoneNumberLabel = phoneNumberLabel.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(">", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)

               //Create an empty string for the contacts name
               var nameToSave = ""
               //See if we can get A frist name
               if contact.givenName == "" {
                   //If Not check for a last name
                   if contact.familyName == "" {
                       //If no last name set name to Unknown Name
                       nameToSave = "Unknown Name"
                   }else{
                       nameToSave = contact.familyName
                   }
               }else{
                   nameToSave = contact.givenName
               }

               // See if we can get image data
               if let imageData = contact.imageData {
                   //If so create the image
                   let userImage = UIImage(data: imageData)
               }
               //Do what you need to do with your new contact information here!
               //Get the string value of the phone number like this:
               actualNumber.stringValue
           }
       }else{
           //If there are no phone numbers associated with the contact I call a custom funciton I wrote that lets me display an alert Controller to the user
           self.displayAlert("Missing info", message: "You have no phone numbers associated with this contact")
       }
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the awesome code! Well, how can I pickup the multiple contacts at a time?

Comment: For multiple contacts selection. Implement `contactPicker(picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelectContacts contacts: [CNContact])`

Comment: Keep in mind that this code needs to check for and/or request access to the user's contacts before presenting the picker.

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

**SWIFT3 IOS10**
Working version of [Jon Vogel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4576323/jon-vogel) for Swift 3 and IOS 10 and support to multiple contacts selection.

```
//
//  Created by JEFFERSON A NEITZKE on 30/01/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 JEFFERSON A NEITZKE. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import ContactsUI

class Principal: UIViewController, CNContactPickerDelegate {

    var numeroADiscar: String = ""
    var userImage: UIImage? = nil
    var nameToSave = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let peoplePicker = CNContactPickerViewController()
        peoplePicker.delegate = self
        self.present(peoplePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {

        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

    }

    func contactPickerDidCancel(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController) {

        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contacts: [CNContact]) {

        // I only want single selection
        if contacts.count != 1 {

            return

        } else {

            //Dismiss the picker VC
            picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

            let contact: CNContact = contacts[0]

            //See if the contact has multiple phone numbers
            if contact.phoneNumbers.count > 1 {

                //If so we need the user to select which phone number we want them to use
                let multiplePhoneNumbersAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Which one?", message: "This contact has multiple phone numbers, which one did you want use?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

                //Loop through all the phone numbers that we got back
                for number in contact.phoneNumbers {

                    //Each object in the phone numbers array has a value property that is a CNPhoneNumber object, Make sure we can get that
                    let actualNumber = number.value as CNPhoneNumber

                    //Get the label for the phone number
                    var phoneNumberLabel = number.label

                    //Strip off all the extra crap that comes through in that label
                    phoneNumberLabel = phoneNumberLabel?.replacingOccurrences(of: "_", with: "")
                    phoneNumberLabel = phoneNumberLabel?.replacingOccurrences(of: "$", with: "")
                    phoneNumberLabel = phoneNumberLabel?.replacingOccurrences(of: "!", with: "")
                    phoneNumberLabel = phoneNumberLabel?.replacingOccurrences(of: "<", with: "")
                    phoneNumberLabel = phoneNumberLabel?.replacingOccurrences(of: ">", with: "")

                    //Create a title for the action for the UIAlertVC that we display to the user to pick phone numbers
                    let actionTitle = phoneNumberLabel! + " - " + actualNumber.stringValue

                    //Create the alert action
                    let numberAction = UIAlertAction(title: actionTitle, style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (theAction) -> Void in

                        //See if we can get A frist name
                        if contact.givenName == "" {

                            //If Not check for a last name
                            if contact.familyName == "" {
                                //If no last name set name to Unknown Name
                                self.nameToSave = "Unknown Name"
                            }else{
                                self.nameToSave = contact.familyName
                            }

                        } else {

                            self.nameToSave = contact.givenName

                        }

                        // See if we can get image data
                        if let imageData = contact.imageData {
                            //If so create the image
                            self.userImage = UIImage(data: imageData)!
                        }

                        //Do what you need to do with your new contact information here!
                        //Get the string value of the phone number like this:
                        self.numeroADiscar = actualNumber.stringValue

                    })

                    //Add the action to the AlertController
                    multiplePhoneNumbersAlert.addAction(numberAction)

                }

                //Add a cancel action
                let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: { (theAction) -> Void in
                    //Cancel action completion
                })

                //Add the cancel action
                multiplePhoneNumbersAlert.addAction(cancelAction)

                //Present the ALert controller
                self.present(multiplePhoneNumbersAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

            } else {

                //Make sure we have at least one phone number
                if contact.phoneNumbers.count > 0 {

                    //If so get the CNPhoneNumber object from the first item in the array of phone numbers
                    let actualNumber = (contact.phoneNumbers.first?.value)! as CNPhoneNumber

                    //Get the label of the phone number
                    var phoneNumberLabel = contact.phoneNumbers.first!.label

                    //Strip out the stuff you don't need
                    phoneNumberLabel = phoneNumberLabel?.replacingOccurrences(of: "_", with: "")
                    phoneNumberLabel = phoneNumberLabel?.replacingOccurrences(of: "$", with: "")
                    phoneNumberLabel = phoneNumberLabel?.replacingOccurrences(of: "!", with: "")
                    phoneNumberLabel = phoneNumberLabel?.replacingOccurrences(of: "<", with: "")
                    phoneNumberLabel = phoneNumberLabel?.replacingOccurrences(of: ">", with: "")

                    //Create an empty string for the contacts name
                    self.nameToSave = ""
                    //See if we can get A frist name
                    if contact.givenName == "" {
                        //If Not check for a last name
                        if contact.familyName == "" {
                            //If no last name set name to Unknown Name
                            self.nameToSave = "Unknown Name"
                        }else{
                            self.nameToSave = contact.familyName
                        }
                    } else {
                        nameToSave = contact.givenName
                    }

                    // See if we can get image data
                    if let imageData = contact.imageData {
                        //If so create the image
                        self.userImage = UIImage(data: imageData)
                    }

                    //Do what you need to do with your new contact information here!
                    //Get the string value of the phone number like this:
                    self.numeroADiscar = actualNumber.stringValue

                } else {

                    //If there are no phone numbers associated with the contact I call a custom funciton I wrote that lets me display an alert Controller to the user
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Missing info", message: "You have no phone numbers associated with this contact", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                    alert.addAction(cancelAction)
                    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```