# Showing error : No Such module Contacts

Tags: swift, contacts

I am trying to implement contact details from iphone. but getting error

[image: Showing error No such module Contacts]

Answer (score 1):

In your project build settings, under the general tab, find the section for `Linked frameworks and Libraries`.

Then find and add `Contacts.framework` (and optionally ContactsUI.framework) to your project.

Do a clean rebuild of your project to be sure.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

It shows because in iOS9 new Contacts framework has been integrated named "ContactsUI".

so, `import ContactsUI` in your file.

Reference Example:

[How to select a contact with ABPeoplePickerNavigationController in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25218399/how-to-select-a-contact-with-abpeoplepickernavigationcontroller-in-swift)

Comment: That is not correct. If you check the attached link, `import Contacts` is correct. Contacts and ContactsUI framework were introduced to replace the Address Book and Address Book UI frameworks.
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Contacts/Reference/Contacts_Framework/index.html